# Using "adb shell" in Python

Tags: python, adb

So I decided to create very simple "ADB Installer" Python app for installing builds and taking screenshots on Android devices using the os.system / os.popen lines, like for example:

```
os.system("adb connect " + IP)
```

etc. But now I am kind of stuck, because i need to send this (which works OK in bash script I use as a base for my Python app):

```
  adb shell "
  cd [path] 
  rm -r [app name]
  exit
  "
```

How do I do this using os.system / os.popen please? (I really tried to avoid using adb-shell and other Python implementations, but if there is no other way then I will try it).
Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify why `os.system` doesn't work for you? Isn't the string in the `adb shell` example just a param to the command?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, maybe the os.system will work, I am just not sure how to write it (I am really a beginner with Python, sorry). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using triplequotes, you can get multiple lines within a string. Not sure if this'll work, but it's what I would try.

```
os.system("""adb shell "
  cd [path] 
  rm -r [app name]
  exit
  " """)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using subprocess:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

path = "[path]"
app_name = "[app name]"
commands_array = ["adb","shell", "rm", path + "/" + app_name , "&&", 
                  "ls", "-la", path]
try:
    result = run(commands_array, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, 
                  check=True, universal_newlines=True)
except Exception as e:
   print("An error occured:")
   print(e)

print(result.stdout)
```